# Using my private DNS from within AWS VPC via Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-route53

I have an Amazon VPC connected to our corporate network. Each EC2/beanstalk (linux) instance uses the standard AWS supplied IP address for its name server in /etc/resolv.conf. Each EC2 instance can also route back into the corporate network with no problem, so for instance I can run this:

$ nslookup server.corp-domain.com 10.10.10.1

and it resolves with no problem, the EC2 instance can talk to 10.10.10.1

(corp-domain.com does not resolve on the internet, it is only used on our internal corporate network. 10.10.10.1 is a name server on our corporate network.)

I want to be able to run that without specifying the corp nameserver IP address, ie, make it use the entry in /etc/resolv.conf

So it boils down to - how do I make Route 53 pass DNS queries in the corp-domain.com back to our corporate nameserver?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you've requested.  The AWS supplied DNS servers within the VPC cannot be configured to pass requests to your corporate DNS server.  You would need to run your own DNS server(s) within the VPC which know to forward queries for server.corp-domain.com to 10.10.10.1, and use the AWS VPC DNS servers for everything else.

Comment: I believe this may be possible now, at least in certain cases using Private Hosted Zones for VPC.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-private-hosted-zones

Comment: Not really; that allows you to have private zones accessible only within the VPC, which while of immense value (I use them regularly), do not connect up or resolve via any zones (private or otherwise) on your Corporate network (i.e.over a VPN).