# ec2 route53 + openwrt: openwrt as nameserver in ec2 vpc

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-route53

I have an OpenWRT router with an IP reachable within an Amazon EC2 VPC. The router is running a dnsmasq server.

Router IP is 192.168.13.1. A client is connected to the router with hostname 'iPhone' with IP 192.168.13.117.

VPC domain is examplevpc.com

I want all DNS queries within the VPC for *.routername.examplevpc.com to resolve via the dnsmasq server at 192.168.13.1. For example a query for iphone.routername.examplevpc.com should return 192.168.13.117.

From a server within the VPC, I can successfully run `nslookup iPhone 192.168.13.1` and get the iPhone IP address. `dig iPhone @192.168.13.1` also works.

I tried adding an NS entry `routername.examplevpc.com` -> `192.168.13.1` to route53 for the VPC but it does not work -- `dig iPhone.routername.examplevpc.com` responds with `NXDOMAIN`. Do I need to do something additionally?

**EDIT:**

---

So I found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/703802/using-my-private-dns-from-within-aws-vpc-via-route-53) which said I needed to setup DNS forwarding within the VPC.  So I setup a DNS forwarder at `172.28.0.5`:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-28-1-13:~$ nslookup hostname.routername.vpcdomain.net 172.28.0.5
Server:         172.28.0.5
Address:        172.28.0.5#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   hostname.routername.vpcdomain.net
Address: 192.168.13.89
```

I then did what @dsmsk80 suggested in his comment:

```
A record: ns1.vpcdomain.net -> 172.28.0.5
NS record: routername.vpcdomain.net -> ns1.vpcdomain.net.
```

This is the failed output of `dig`:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-28-1-13:~$ dig hostname.routername.vpcdomain.net

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.2-Ubuntu <<>> hostname.routername.vpcdomain.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 52300
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hostname.routername.vpcdomain.net.      IN      A

;; Query time: 20 msec
;; SERVER: 172.28.0.2#53(172.28.0.2)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 27 19:37:29 UTC 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 53
```

However when directly specifying the nameserver it works as expected:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-28-1-13:~$ dig hostname.routername.vpcdomain.net @ns1.vpcdomain.net

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.2-Ubuntu <<>> hostname.routername.vpcdomain.net @ns1.vpcdomain.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50111
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hostname.routername.vpcdomain.net.      IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
hostname.routername.vpcdomain.net. 0     IN      A       192.168.13.89

;; Query time: 33 msec
;; SERVER: 172.28.0.5#53(172.28.0.5)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 27 19:38:35 UTC 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 69
```

and also with `nslookup`:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-28-1-13:~$ nslookup hostname.routername.vpcdomain.net ns1.vpcdomain.net
Server:         ns1.vpcdomain.net
Address:        172.28.0.5#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   hostname.routername.vpcdomain.net
Address: 192.168.13.89
```

Here is the config on openwrt:

```
config dnsmasq
        option domainneeded     1
        option boguspriv        1
        option filterwin2k      0  # enable for dial on demand
        option localise_queries 1
        option rebind_protection 1  # disable if upstream must serve RFC1918 addresses
        option rebind_localhost 1  # enable for RBL checking and similar services
        #list rebind_domain example.lan  # whitelist RFC1918 responses for domains
        option local    '/routername.vpcdomain.net/'
        option domain   'routername.vpcdomain.net.'
        option expandhosts      1
        option nonegcache       0
        option authoritative    1
        option readethers       1
        option leasefile        '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
        option resolvfile       '/tmp/resolv.conf.auto'
        #list server            '/mycompany.local/1.2.3.4'
        #option nonwildcard     1
        #list interface         br-lan
        #list notinterface      lo
        #list bogusnxdomain     '64.94.110.11'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you are allowed to use  a [domain-name with NS records only](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) which specifies a host which should be authoritative for the specified class and domain.

So what happens if you add these records to your zone?

```
A record: routername-ns1.examplevpc.com. -> 192.168.13.1
NS record: routername.examplevpc.com. -> routername-ns1.examplevpc.com.
```

Or shorter form:

```
A record: routername-ns1 -> 192.168.13.1
NS record: routername -> routername-ns1.examplevpc.com.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer...

Confusingly documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html

I had to explicitly set my private DNS server via VPC DHCP options set.